# Eclipse Jar File no resources

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, text-files

--closed, figured it out by myself--

(Answer: Jar File does not compress Pictures or TextFiles in itself, you       have to make a Folder with the Jar File inside and the a FileSystem similar to how you called your Files. For Example if xou Called a File: Example.txt, just put this File inside the Folder with the JarFile, if you called: ExampleFolder/Example.txt, put a Folder named ExampleFolder with the Example.txt in it, next to the JarFile, See the Pattern?)

I have a problem with Eclipse.
I made a program which gets information from textfiles so it can do the things I want it to do. In Eclipse everything works fine, it does load the data out of the Files and writes it back into them. But when I export it as a runnable jar-File, the program can't find the resources. I already read some explanasions about how to fix that with InputStreams, but I didn't understand that, maby one of you can help me.

Code for getting information out of the Files:

```
// all Lines in a TextFile is made an array
    public static String[] exFileContains(String file) {
        // temporary number
        int ctr = 0;
        try {// counts how many lines the file has
            Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(file));
            while (s1.hasNextLine()) {
                ctr++;
                s1.nextLine();
            }
            // creates String Array with enough room for the file        contains
            String[] contains = new String[ctr];
            // Declares which line gets which Array space
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File(file));
            for (int i = 0; i < ctr; i++) {
                contains[i] = s2.nextLine();
            } // gives this Array back to the Project Creator
            return contains;
            // if the program can't use or find the file
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            NewProjektErrors.missingFile();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

in Eclipse the Array contains all what was inside of the file, as Jar File the Array is empty, cause somehow it can't use the File anymore

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Please post the code you use for loading the files (edit the question and add the code).

Comment: It might also help to post the exact error/exception you're getting, and what line its being thrown on. Also, what is the value of `String file` being passed in?

Comment: The Error is not the problem, I have a File with 5 words, every Word in a new Line, so every Arrayspace takes one word. if I for example want to display the words in a JFrame, it works as long as it is inside Eclipse, if I export it as a Jar File, and start the Program, there is nothing displayed cause it couldn't somehow use this File

Comment: Offtopic but still crucial - close your scanners!!!

Comment: You're right, I missed to close them again. Done now but doesn't help with my problem :'D